# Can I write a "new command" for Visual Studio 2015 that comments out lines in a txt file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The file is written in a language not supported by Visual Studio (it's the language used to mod Stellaris, a game by Paradox. A very strange language by the way).

They are saved as txt files. the comment in this language is any line that starts with a #

Is it possible, and easy, to write some kind of extension for Visual Studio to comment out lines in a txt file with #?

Maybe I could use find and replace but I'm not sure what the regular expression would be (I don't want to double comment, and I wouldn't be replacing anything, so it would have to be something like "add a # to the begining of any line that doesn't start with a #).

If there's a way to do it find and replace, then there's probably a way to write an extension to add this command too. Or maybe there's already an extension that lets you add random characters at the begining of lines?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: hope this question gets the attention it deserves

Answer (score 1):

You can write the following C# command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
{
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    EnvDTE.TextDocument doc = DTE.ActiveDocument.Object("TextDocument") as EnvDTE.TextDocument;
    EnvDTE.EditPoint p = doc.CreateEditPoint();
    for (int i = ts.TopLine; i <= ts.BottomLine; ++i)
    {
        p.MoveToLineAndOffset(i, 1);
        p.Insert("#");
    }
}
```

It can comment both the current line or the selected lines.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't test it yet, I had a lot of homework today and now I'm going to bed. I'll try that tomorrow after school, thank you.